# Error on breaks argument when using the cut function

Tags: r, cut

I'm learning R and I need to create a two way table from the data below:

```
> head(datanet)
   Date & Time [Local]  distance travelled
1:    18/06/2018 03:08  15.959366
2:    18/06/2018 03:12  22.535566
3:    18/06/2018 03:16  12.036834
4:    18/06/2018 03:20  18.738134
5:    18/06/2018 03:24  26.781879
6:    18/06/2018 03:28  8.341659
```

My desired output should look like the table below, having an `hour` column entry representing the time of the day (24 entries for the 24 hours of the day) and several `dist_tra on yyyy-mm-dd` entries with the average hourly distance travelled per day for each hour of the day. Like so:

```
head(dist.byHour[1:3])
  hour dist_tra on 06/07/2018  dist_tra on 06/08/2018
1:   00              25.834355              29.388140
2:   01                     NA               8.329956
3:   02                     NA              31.506390
4:   03              33.464954              20.995957
5:   04               6.406513              17.035749
6:   05              28.254438              38.803171
```

By looking online and talking to some collegues I got the script below. However, I'm having an undesired error message when using `cut()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

datanet$datehour <- cut(datanet[[1]], breaks = "hours")

dist.byHour <- aggregate(meters ~ datehour, datanet, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
dist.byHour$datehour <- as.POSIXct(dist.byHour$datehour)
dist.byHour$hour <- format(dist.byHour$datehour, "%H")
dist.byHour$datehour <- as.Date(dist.byHour$datehour)
dist.byHour <- dist.byHour[c(3, 1, 2)]

dist.byHour <- dist.byHour %>%
  spread(datehour, -hour)

names(dist.byHour)[-1] <- paste("dist_tra on", names(dist.byHour)[-1])
```

The error being:

```
> datanet$datehour <- cut(datanet[[1]], breaks = "hours")
Error in cut.default(datanet[[1]], breaks = "hours") : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? This is an important assignment I'm working on so any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: You need to coerce the datetime strings to an actual datetime class *before* you use `cut` and not afterwards.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for for your message. What do you mean by coercing? Is there a quick way to do that considering the type of data I have (`datanet`)?

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's no need to use cut, you can just use groups:

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

# sample data
date <- c("18/06/2018 03:08", "18/06/2018 03:12", "18/06/2018 04:20", "19/06/2018 03:16", "19/06/2018 03:20", "19/06/2018 04:20")
distance <- c(15.959366,  22.535566, 12.036834,  18.738134, 12.036834, 22.535566)

df <- data.frame(date, distance)

df %>% 
  mutate(date = dmy_hm(date)) %>% #coerce to date object
  group_by(day = date(date), hour = hour(date)) %>% # group by day and hour
  summarise(dist = mean(distance)) %>% # average distance traveled in that hour
  spread(day, dist) # re-arrange dataframe
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked to perfection. I was wondering if there was the possibility to include column headers that format the date in the same way as seen on the `head(dist.byHour[1:3])` sample of my original post? Now the column headers are formated as `yyyy-mm-dd` and not `mm/dd/yyyy`. Hope you can let me know something!

Comment: either play around with date formatting or just hack it in at the end with   `set_names(c("hour", "dist_tra on 06/07/2018", "dist_tra on 06/08/2018"))`